# Getting disk i/o statistics for single process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, disk-usage

I need to monitor the I/O statistics of a process that writes to disk. The purpose is to avoid write rates too high for long periods.

I know there's `iostat` tool to accomplish this task on a system-wide perspective.

Is there something similar to monitor single process disk usage?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/169676/howto-check-disk-i-o-utilisation-per-process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/). Most distributions have a package for it, usually called (logically enough) `iotop`.

One very cool command (at least, on a system that isn't very busy) is `iotop -bo`. This will show I/O as it occurs. It also has options to only monitor specific processes or processes owned by specified users.

Comment: thank you, exactly what I wanted :) 
I ca also filter output of iotop -boP with grep to show only stats of the process I want :)

Comment: What if you don't have root access, as `iotop` requires?