# How can I plot disk io per process over time

Tags: monitoring

I would like to analyze and visualize the disk through put of certain processes over time to see how much data is written to disk and to see at which times a process does not utilize the whole disk performance capability. For example because its doing a CPU intensive tasks or because it accesses a lot of small files and the disk needs to do a lot of head repositioning.

I already know about this question: [How can I monitor disk io](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55212/15065). It shows how I can monitor disk IO per process. In particular `iotop -aoP` shows the cumulative IO per process. This is nice if I want to track for example how much data a process has already written since IO top was started. But it does a bad job in visualizing the data over time.

**Part 1: Essentially I am looking for something similar to the network history in `gnome-system-monitor` but listed per process and not totally for the whole disk.**

Secondly the process that writes to disk does not necessarily have to be the process that causes the IO. For example if I access an NTFS file-system, then the data is first written to `mount.ntfs-3g` which writes it to disk. So if I want to track the performance of a `qemu` process writing to an img file thats on an NTFS storage then I see all the IO happen on the `mount.ntfs-3g` process and non on the qemu process. I assume the data is piped from the `qemu` process to the `mount.ntfs-3g` processes before it is written do disk.

**Part 2: So the second part of the question is if I can somehow visualize the IO only for the qemu process.**

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21295/getting-disk-i-o-statistics-for-single-process-in-linux | https://serverfault.com/questions/169676/how-to-check-disk-i-o-utilization-per-process

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `top` command for a certain disk drive, or if you really want to be specific use `iostat -xd /proc`.

Comment: I was looking rather for a graphical solution that gives me a chart. And your solution also does not consider a certain process but all in proc.